# Multi column HTML list with a set number of items in first column?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I had a look here http://novitskisoftware.com/test/multiplecolumnsEms.html and at various other sites for making a multi column list and it works fine.

What I wonder is if let's say I have a dynamic list and if there are for example 10 list items I want to keep eight of them in the first column and the rest in the second, i.e. always 8 items in first columns if there are more than 8 of them.

I assume this is not possible with only CSS/HTML so is it something I can do with JavaScript/jQuery? I prefer to keep the plugin's to  a minimum.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like something that you could easily do on the server side.

Comment: I don't control how the HTML gets generated though (SharePoint navigation).

Comment: are you building the list items with any logic , i mean it's a part of any algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the HTML page generated contains:

```
<ul>
    <li class="item1">A</li>
    <li class="item2">B</li>
    <li class="item3">C</li>
    <li class="item4">D</li>
    <li class="item5">E</li>
    <li class="item6">F</li>
    <li class="item7">G</li>
    <li class="item8">H</li>
    <li class="item9">I</li>
    <li class="item10">J</li>
    <li class="item11">K</li>
    <li class="item12">L</li>
    <li class="item13">M</li>
    <li class="item14">N</li>
    <li class="item15">O</li>
</ul>
```

You may now use JavaScript to generate the required CSS as follows:

```
/*
    unorderedList: the HTML ul element
    columnSize:    the number of items per column
    columnGap:     the distance between 2 columns in ems
    offset:        the offset of the first column in ems
*/

function generateMultiColumnLayout(unorderedList, columnSize, columnGap, offset) {
    var items = unorderedList.getElementsByTagName("li");

    for (var i = 0, l = items.length; l--; i++) {
        var itemStyle = items[i].style;
        itemStyle.lineHeight = "1.2em";

        if (!i && i % columnSize) {                   // old column
            itemStyle.marginLeft = offset + "em";
        } else {                                      // start of new column
            offset += columnGap;
            itemStyle.marginLeft = offset + "em";
            itemStyle.marginTop = -columnSize + "em";
        }
    }
}

window.onload = function () {
    var items = document.getElementsByClassName("item1");

    for (var i = 0, l = items.length; l--; i++) {
        generateMultiColumnLayout(items[i].parent, 8, 10, 5);
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use a table for this? You can even create the table with Javascript using the DOM manipulation methods if you so wish.

Comment: As another html/js noob it would be nice to know why this is a down voted answer. Inserting stuff into a table seems like a reasonable way to go for this problem.

Comment: @worldsayshi: If you really really don't want to change the document structure you basically are forced to use the approach in the accepted answer. If you OK with modifying the document structure you could use a table or you could use a separate divs for each of the two sections, putting the subitems inside those.